# Can't insert into a DB with a Web Service PHP and Nusoap

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-services, nusoap

I'm developing a API for my work, and we need to do a Web Service, to later we consume it. I followed many tutorials to do the Web Service, but I still cant make it work.  I just need that the Web Service can insert into a DB, but it only return me bool(false). I'm using Nusoap lib. 
This is my index.php (the service), I'm using XAMPP for localhost.

```
<?php 
    require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/s/lib/nusoap.php';     

    $server = new nusoap_server(); 
    $server->configureWSDL("RecibirDatosXML", "urn:RecibirDatosXMLwsdl");
    $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = "urn:RecibirDatosXMLwsdl";

    function RecibirDatos($datos) {

      session_start();

            $servidor="localhost"; 
            $db="prueba"; 
            $user="root"; 
            $pass=""; 
            $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor,$user,$pass,$db);

             $sql = "INSERT INTO registro (Nombre,Apellido,Email,Usuario,Contraseña) VALUES('Nombasrae, 'Apellido', 'Email', 'Usuario', 'Contraseña')";
            mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) or die ("Error"); //I think the error is here
               mysqli_close($conexion);


        return "Hi $datos "; //If Insert then return it
    }

    $server->register(
        "RecibirDatos",
        array('datos' => 'xsd:string'), // Parámetros de entrada
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'),
        'urn:RecibirDatosXMLwsdl', // Nombre del workspace
        'urn:RecibirDatosXMLwsdl#RecibirDatos', // Acción soap
        'rpc', // Estilo
        'encoded', // Uso
        'Manda los datos para ser procesados' // Documentación
    );

    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) ? $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';

    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

   ?>
```

And this is my prueba.php where I consuming the Web Service...

```
<?php
require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/s/lib/nusoap.php';
$client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/s/index.php?wsdl');

$result = $client->call('RecibirDatos',array('datos' => 'Clark'));

      if ($client->fault) {
           echo 'Error: ';
           print_r($result);
      } else {
         // check result
      $err_msg = $client->getError();
      if ($err_msg) {
          // Print error msg
         echo 'Error: '.$err_msg;
      } else {
          // Print result
         echo 'Result: ';
         print_r($result);
      }
   }
?>
```

The Web Service only answer me "bool(false)", if I comment the DB code, it works and returns me "Hi Clark".  The error occurs when I do the SQL.

Debugging the Web Service the answer is:

> Error: Response not of type text/xml: text/html; charset=UTF-8

I think the error is in the sql because if I delete the "or die" instruction
it print "Hi Clark", so i think that for one weird reason the sql query cant success and then go to "or die" and the service try to print "Error" and then the Web Service answer me "Error: Response not of type text/xml: text/html; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: What errors do you see? Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: Also, to be safe, edit the insert statement and include the column names.

Comment: I also edited the insert statement and included the column names and it keep returning "bool (false)" from the Web Service

Comment: Try commenting out the web service calls, and echo the results. Also turn on error reporting.

Comment: Done, What do you think now?

Comment: I meant to test the SQL outside of the web service and see what error message you are getting from that.